# Automated backup of sql server using batch files

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a stored procedure which takes 3 arguments

databaseName 
backupType 
backupLocation

if i run this stored procedure its creating the backup.
I want to know hw to write a batch file for this and schedule a job to run at specified time.
I am using sqlserver2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article:

[sqlcmd utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

You can use the sqlcmd utility in a batch file to execute your procedure.

Answer (score 1):

you can Refer this microsoft link:
This is a microsift link with stored procedure and batch file examples

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019698